# R S4 overloading of subscript operator for base matrix class

Tags: r, operator-overloading, r-s4

I have defined a S4 class called *FilterCommandIndices* this way:

```
setClass('FilterCommandIndices',
     representation(rows='logical', cols='logical')
     )
```

It just contains two slots, logical vectors indicating whether a given row or column is included in a set. Then I want to overload the subscript operator for it to work with the previous class. My initial implementation goes like this:

```
setMethod('[', c(x='ANY', i='FilterCommandIndices', j='missing'),
      function(x, i, j, ..., drop=TRUE) {
        if (nrow(x) != length(getRows(i)) || ncol(x) != length(getCols(i))) {
          stop('Incorrect number of dimensions')
        } else {
          return(x[getRows(i), getCols(i)])
        }
      })
```

In the previous code, *getRows*() and *getCols*() are the corresponding trivial accessors for the *FilterCommandIndices* class:

```
setGeneric('getRows', function(object) standardGeneric('getRows'))

setMethod('getRows', 'FilterCommandIndices',
      function(object) {
        return(object@rows)
      })

setGeneric('getCols', function(object) standardGeneric('getCols'))

setMethod('getCols', 'FilterCommandIndices',
      function(object) {
        return(object@cols)
      })
```

I thought that by using the *ANY* signature, I could make this simple class and operator combination to work even in base classes, like a simple *matrix*. Although it seems to work on an example class...

```
d> bar1
An object of class "FilterCommandIndices"
Slot "rows":
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

Slot "cols":
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

d> mockMethylSet
MethylSet (storageMode: lockedEnvironment)
assayData: 5 features, 5 samples 
  element names: Meth, Unmeth 
phenoData: none
Annotation
Preprocessing
  Method: unknown
  minfi version: unknown
  Manifest version: unknown

d> mockMethylSet[bar1]
MethylSet (storageMode: lockedEnvironment)
assayData: 4 features, 5 samples 
  element names: Meth, Unmeth 
phenoData: none
Annotation
Preprocessing
   Method: unknown
  minfi version: unknown
  Manifest version: unknown
```

...but not in the base *matrix* class:

```
d> zeroDetectionP
   S1 S2 S3 S4 S5
F1  0  0  0  0  0
F2  0  0  0  0  0
F3  0  0  0  0  0
F4  0  0  0  0  0
F5  0  0  0  0  0

d> zeroDetectionP[bar1]
Error en zeroDetectionP[bar1] : invalid subscript type 'S4'
```

In the *setMethod* docs, it says that you can define methods using base classes in the signature, what made me think that I could implement something like the previous method using an *ANY* signature and failing only when the subscripted object does not implement *nrow*(), *ncol*() or the operator '['.

Any help or hint will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE: Set a specific signature method (as @hadley suggested)**

If I set a method with a specific signature for the matrix base class...

```
d> getMethod('[', c(x='matrix', i='FilterCommandIndices', j='missing'))
Method Definition:

function (x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) 
{
    return(x) # Dummy method
}
```

... and then try again to subscript a matrix...

```
d> zeroDetectionP[bar1]
Error en zeroDetectionP[bar1] : invalid subscript type 'S4'
```

... the error is still there.

**UPDATE: Minimal reproducible example**

I have tried to write a minimal scenario where I could reproduce the previous scenario. This is, I think, a simple scenario that gives the same error. As @hadley suggested, it might be due to the subscript being a primitive.

```
library(methods)

setClass('Indices', representation(rows='logical', cols='logical'))

setMethod('[', c(x='ANY', i='Indices', j='missing'),
      function(x, i, j, ..., drop=FALSE) {
        return(x[i@rows, i@cols])
      })

setClass('M', representation(m='matrix'))

setMethod('[', c(x='M', i='logical', j='logical'),
      function(x, i, j, ..., drop=FALSE) {
        return(x@m[i, j])
      })

anIndicesObject <- new('Indices', rows=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), cols=c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
aMatrix <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
aMobject <- new('M', m=aMatrix)

aMobject # Prints the M object
aMobject[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)] # Susbcript by logical vector
aMobject[anIndicesObject] # Subscript by Indices class
aMatrix[anIndicesObject] # Subscript a matrix by Indices --> ERROR
```

Comment: Try an explicit `setMethod('[', c(x='matrix', i='FilterCommandIndices', j='missing')` ?

Comment: I have already. Edited the question to add that extra information.

Comment: Hmmm, might be because `[` is primitive. But you're more likely to get help if you produce a _minimal_ reproducible example that can be easily copy and pasted into R.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the scenario was simple enough. I have edited the question to provide what I think is a minimal example. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even more minimal reproducible example:

```
library(methods)

setClass("Indices", representation(rows = "logical", cols = "logical"))
x <- new("Indices", rows=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), cols=c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
m <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
m[x]

# Method doesn't appear to be found for signature x = "ANY"
show_s4 <- function(x, i, j, ..., drop=FALSE) "S4"
setMethod("[", signature(x = "ANY", i = "Indices", j = "missing"), show_s4)
m[x]

# Or even with explicit "matrix" in signature
setMethod("[", signature(x = "matrix", i = "Indices"), show_s4)
m[x]
# Error in m[x] : invalid subscript type "S4"

# Describing all arguments also fails
getGeneric("[")
setMethod(
  "[", 
  signature(x = "matrix", i = "Indices", j = "missing", drop = "missing"),
  show_s4
)
m[x]
```

I think the key is this sentence in `?Methods`:

> An S4 method alone will not be seen if the S3 generic function 
>   is called directly. However, primitive functions and operators 
>   are exceptions: The internal C code will look for S4 methods if and 
>   only if the object is an S4 object.

Since matrix is not an S4 class, you can not dispatch on it in internally generic methods (like `[`)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! now it makes sense, at least all the sense I can get from that sentence in ?Methods. Thank you for your time.